# Azure AD Connect organization migration

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect an unconnected organization to my company's Active directory.

The error i get is :

Organization abcdefg connection to an AAD Tenant failed due to the error : No PCAs found with the identity signin address

Anyone knows what can be possibly going wrong?.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have raised it with the product team.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the same issue today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with this and you will likely be unable to do this with a AAD account. I was able to resolve it by:

1. Create new MSA (*@outlook.com) account
2. Add new MSA as Project Collection Admin of Azure DevOps Organisation
3. Add new MSA as guest account in Azure AD Tennant

You can then login to portal.azure.com and connect the Organisation to the desired Azure AD tenant. Then the clean-up begins...

Comment: It works!. Thank you. :). I am ticking your answer as the accepted response.